# Funnel plot limits for indirectly standardized costs and length of stay

Tags: funnel-plot

This paper:

Spiegelhalter, David J. "Funnel plots for comparing institutional performance." Statistics in medicine 24.8 (2005): 1185-1202.

describes funnel plot limits for indirectly standardized rates (such as mortality rates), along with a number of other types of measures.

However, thus far I have been unable to find a method for calculating limits for indirectly standardized data that are not rates. In my case, I have standardized costs and length of stay (LOS) for a number of institutions. These measures are derived for each institution by applying a regression model to each patient (a set of binary variables) to calculate an expected cost or LOS per patient. The model is based on historical data from the same institutions. The standardized cost or LOS is then the sum of the actual cost or LOS divided by the sum of the expected values. I do not have the patient level data (either the binary predictors or the expected for each patient); however, for each institution I have: the standardized measure, Number of patients used for the measure, LOS or cost variance and standard deviation, mean LOS or cost.

According to the above paper, a funnel plot has four components:

1. An indicator *Y*. In this case that is the indirectly standardized
   LOS or cost.
2. A target for *Y* such that expected value of *Y* for an "in-control" institution is equal to that target. In this case the target is 1.
3. A precision parameter that determines the accuracy of the indicator for an institution. In this case, this is the number of patients used for that indicator in an institution.
4. Control limits for a P-value *p*, where the chance of exceeding these limits for an in-control unit is *p*. These are the inverse
   cumulative distribution of p(y | target, precision parameter).

The problem is that I am not sure which distribution I should use for the control limits (item 4). The only funnel plots of LOS in the literature use rates, such as % of patients with a "long" LOS. Since I don't have patient-level data I cannot do this.

I'd appreciate any suggestions, or pointers to work that addresses limits for these kinds of indicators.